# Carrying request context through the stack and across thrift service boundaries with Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, restify

I'm trying to figure out an appropriate method to carry a request-id (x-request-id from a restify request header) through my stack; across thrift inter-service calls, and with rabbitmq queue messages. The goal is that anywhere, in any service, I can correlate an error or event back to an initiating http request. Is there a known practice for doing this with Node? I'd like to avoid passing a context around through virtually every function call.

I've looked into the way New Relic handles instrumentation, and there's this blog: https://opbeat.com/blog/posts/how-we-instrument-nodejs/; but these types of instrumentation require hooking into tons of node core library calls, and don't really help with carrying the context across thrift calls.

How can I take a restify header id such as "x-request-id" from a request, and have access to it deeper in my stack (even in async callbacks) without modifying every function to pass the values through?

I'm also looking for a clean way to pass it through all thrift calls (getting it across service boundaries).

This is with TypeScript and Node.js 5.x

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a known practice for doing this with Node

Within NodeJs you move `request` around whereever you need *request context stuff*.

With every other system you need to carry the stuff around *in the request system format for that thing*. E.g. for Event store we store it in the event metadata.

For thrift I recommend just adding it as a property in every query that is echoed back in every response.

Comment: so the `function(a,b,c, req) { ... } ` method? I was hoping to avoid modifying all of the functions to pass it through, though it is survivable. It seems like a second-class-citizen solution since it doesn't enforce itself / is painful to keep up. the developer has to remember to build it in. modifying the log signatures to need the req doesn't even work since colleagues will likely choose to just not log rather than modify several function signatures to get access to req.

I appreciate the answer, I'm just curious if there's a way to ease the pain of carrying that parameter everywhere.

Comment: Make it the first parameter. Or the second (if you have `err` as the first). That way the developers don't forget to add it.

Comment: I'm investigating passing it through the constructors for classes (instead of each function). We've also been considering bringing in inversify for dependency management - so maybe some static routing methods can extract the context, and configure providers for downstream dependency injection. this could make it nearly transparent, although with Thrift and Queues we will have to use the additional property and the meta data property.

Answer (score 0):

So I know it's a bit late but there is a solution with ASyncLocalStorage. You will find more information [here](https://blog.kuzzle.io/nodejs-14-asynclocalstorage-asynchronous-calls).
I haven't tested it yet, but I'm still deterred by the alleged overhead.